# Вычисление реальных координат спрайта на сцене

Tags: objective-c, ios, spritekit

Если взять спрайт, добавить ему коллизию с миром (чтобы он не выходил за пределы мира) и начать его двигать (например, в цикле прибавлять или отнимать координату по оси Х или Y), его координаты меняются (увеличиваются или уменьшаются в зависимости от стороны движения). Если спрайт упирается в одну из сторон, он останавливается, но координаты спрайта все равно меняются, то есть продолжают расти по заданной оси (как на рисунке).

Как можно узнать реальные координаты спрайта на сцене?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно получить позицию дочернего спрайта(`position`) по отношению к его родителю, а затем использовать `convertPoint:fromNode:` или `convertPoint:toNode:` метод для преобразования из системы координат родительского узла в систему координат сцены. (SKScene наследует от SKNode)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался в конце концов. Даже нашел этот ответ на английском. Правда изначально до конца не понимал как правильно загуглить этот вопрос.